# How can I print $submitted in a region template?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a region--content.tpl.php and am trying to figure out how to print the $submitted variable (usually printed in node.tpl.php).

--- EDIT ---

Including here the final code I used.  This lets you print out the themed user link where as the original code only printed the name as plain text.

```
function theme_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['region'] == 'content') {
    $node = menu_get_object();
    $user = user_load($node->uid);

    if ($node) {
      // Adapted from template_preprocess_node().
      $vars['submitted'] = 'By ' . theme('username', array('account' => $user)) . ' | ' . format_date($node->created, 'short');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region template has no concept of the page context, so it doesn't know about the node by default.

You can give it that context by implementing `hook_preprocess_region()` in your theme's template.php file (or a module file), and seeing if there's a node available there:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['region'] == 'region_name') {
    $node = menu_get_object();

    if ($node) {
      // Adapted from template_preprocess_node().
      $vars['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $node->name, '!datetime' => format_date($node->created)));
    }
  }
}
```

After you clear the caches, your region template on node pages should have the `$submitted` var available to it. Obviously that might need a bit of tweaking to suit your needs.